# How to add Image Overlay in JS with FileReader?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

So far i have managed to get 2 Images on my JS. But i can't get the 1 image above the other. I know it usually works on css with "Z" index but since my images are read by the FileReader I added them into my JS.

**Question:** What do i have to change to get the image on top of the other one on my Code because im pretty sure its almost finished but i simply cannot find the Error...

**My JS:**

```
                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        $($.parseHTML('<div>')).attr('class', 'position-relative')
                            .attr('width','200px')
                            .attr('height','200px')
                            .css('display','inline-block')
                            .css('position','relative !important')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result)
                            .attr('width','200px')
                            .attr('height','200px')
                            .css('display','inline-block')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        $($.parseHTML('<div>')).attr('class', 'position-absolute')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', "/x.png")
                            .attr('height','80px')
                            .addClass("")
                            .css('display','inline-block')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i],);
                }

            }
```

**My HTML:**

```
                <div id="form1">
                    <input value="" type="file" id="images" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
                    <div id="previewHolder" data-item-id-div="" multiple="" class="position-relative">
                        <div class="position-absolute delete-image">
                            <img class="image-deletepreview" height=80px style="margin-right: 10px;" src="/x.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i changed my my JS Code into a 1 liner:

```
                      reader.onload = function(event) {
                        $($.parseHTML('<div>')).attr('class', 'position-relative')
                            .attr('width','200px')
                            .attr('height','200px')
                            .css('display','inline-block')
                            .css('position','relative !important')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result)
                            .attr('width','200px')
                            .attr('height','200px')
                            .css('display','inline-block')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        $($.parseHTML('<div>')).attr('class', 'position-absolute')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', "/x.png")
                            .attr('height','80px')
                            .addClass("")
                            .css('display','inline-block')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    }
```

To this:

```
                     reader.onload = function(event) {
                        $('<div class="position-relative" style="height:200px;width: 200px; display: inline-block; position: relative !important;">' +
                            '<img alt="" src='+event.target.result+' style="height:200px;width: 100%; display: inline-block;">' +
                            '<div class="position-absolute" style="top: 0;right: 0;">' +
                            '<img src="/x.png" class="image-deletepreview" style="height: 20px; display: inline-block;"></div></div>')
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);

                    }
```

I just changed the Div to Position 0 and it worked like a Charm.